# jQuery command not giving desired outcome

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wish to add `active` to the className of the last img element in there using html jquery

I have some elements in HTML and jquery as bellow:

```js
function initialSteps() {
  $(".row").find("column:last").find("img:first").className += " active";
  // this does not work either
  //$(".row").find("column:last").find("demo cursor:last").className += " active";

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img class="demo cursor" src="img00.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img class="demo cursor" src="img01.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img class="demo cursor" src="img02.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img class="demo cursor" src="img03.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img class="demo cursor" src="img04.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img class="demo cursor" src="img05.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

However, it does not work.  Could someone show me what I did wrong?

Comment: I answered you, anyway I would like to tell your mistake here. The first is that `column` is a class so you need to add a dot before the selector `.column:last`. The other error is that jquery return a wrapper object and the `className` is html native, so you need to get the native html elemente saying `jqueryobject[0].className += " active“ and it will work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to take advantage of the [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) function in jQuery:

```
function initialSteps() {
  $(".row").find(".column:last").find("img:first").addClass("active");
}
```

Which you could likely shorten by chaining your selectors as follows:

```
function initialSteps() {
   $(".row .column:last img:first").addClass("active");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `.column` instead of `column` and `addClass()`

```js
$(".row").find(".column:last").find("img:first").addClass("active")
```

```css
.active {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img class="demo cursor" src="img00.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img class="demo cursor" src="img01.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img class="demo cursor" src="img02.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img class="demo cursor" src="img03.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img class="demo cursor" src="img04.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img class="demo cursor" src="img05.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Checked Boxes</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img00.jpg"> </div>
  <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img01.jpg"> </div>
  <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img02.jpg"> </div>
  <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img03.jpg"> </div>
  <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img04.jpg"> </div>
  <div class="column"> <img class="demo cursor" src="img05.jpg"> </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "div.row .column:last-child" ).find("img:first").addClass("active");
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it the wrong way. You can not append value for the class using "+" operator.

**jQuery has the inbuilt method for add new class in any element.**

*You can use the below function instead of yours.*

```
function initialSteps() {
   $(".row").find(".column:last").find("img:first").addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make much more simple:

```
function initialSteps() {
  $(".column:last-child img:first-child").addClass("active");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to concatenate so many `find`, just add the full selector once and will be more efficient

```
function initialSteps() {
  $(".row .column:last img").addClass('active') 

}
```